# Using variable to specify the R object

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Java. So pardon me for asking such simple question.

---

To set the background-image of a view, I can do that by

```
int TheButton = R.drawable.button1;   
button.setBackgroundResource(TheButton);
```

But how can this be done if I want to use a variable to specify the R object?

```
int a = 1;
int TheButton = R.drawable["button"+a]; //this is what I'll do in javascript...  
button.setBackgroundResource(TheButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
         String variable="button" + a;
         int Button = getResources().getIdentifier(variable, "drawable",  getPackageName()); 
         //Whatever you want to do..
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can't access resources that way, because when android compiles your application it translates all these fields to **Constant** Value (int).

So you need to write your own mapper to get the results you're expecting, for example you can put all of the related resources in an array:

```
int[] myResourceArray = new int[]{R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second ...};
button.setBackgroundResource(myResourceArray[0]);
...
button.setBackgroundResource(myResourceArray[1]);
```

Or you can use the way @Sercan Suggested, but according to android's documentations they discourage using it for performance reasons. take a look here : [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

When we use `R.drawable.button1` it refers to a `int` element in `drawable` class  which is in  `R`  class. R.java is a self generated class  in gen folder.

So `int TheButton = R.drawable["button"+a];` will not work.

if you want to assign a particular id from js then you can directly use the code copied from R.java like  `int TheButton =0x7f080002;`  copied from R.java

OR

```
int TheButton = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all, since in java variables are typed, you can't add an int to a character sequence.

Secondly you can't use a string to call a public variable from a class (in this case the auto generated R class).

Third point, if tou want to use many drawable on a Button and switch between them i suggest you to use the level-list drawable or the state-liste drawable.

have a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html